# Getting 502 in nginx inside the container -- connection refused

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I am trying to bring up my laravel project with docker (nginx, php) but i keep getting 502 when i run the project under docker-compose up -d .
and In my docker-compose.yml I have :

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    image: rating
    container_name: rating-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/
    networks:
      - rating

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: rating-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8000:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - rating
networks:
  rating:
```

and in the nginx conf :

```
server {
listen 80;
index index.php index.html;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
root /var/www/public;
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
}
```

}

and also in the app dockerfile:

```
    FROM php:7.4

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www
COPY database/ database/
COPY composer.json composer.json
RUN composer install \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-scripts \
    --no-dev \
    --prefer-dist
COPY . .
RUN composer dump-autoload
RUN php artisan optimize:clear

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
EXPOSE 8000
```

I have all the necessary configs in place but i get 502 connection refused when i run docker-compose up -d after building the containers. any thoughts?

Comment: Check the port number. Your php is serving on port 8000, and your nginx try to pass php request to port 9000.

Comment: From your compose description and your nginx config file, it looks like you are using the wrong php base image for your build. You expect you webserver to call your php container as a fastcgi helper on port 9000. This is what is provided when you setup your php container as a FPM (FastCGI Process Manager) which is provided out of the box by the `php:7.4-fpm` image.

Comment: @J. Song  I changed the port to 8000, still the same error

Comment: @AlirezaAmrollahi  You changed wrong port. I mean, your php runs on port 8000. Look at the last part of your Dockerfile. So, php is wating on port 8000. But your nginx.conf file, php request are passed to port 9000. You must fix this first.

Comment: @J.Song I did that, no luck